# Transition not working (white-space: nowrap -> white-space: normal)

Tags: javascript, css, web, transition

As I know, transition not working in my case. Of course, I can add max-height and z-index (and animate it), but I need ellipsis with smooth transition.

`My code here:` 
https://jsfiddle.net/57oknf1f/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with javascript. I write a simple demo for you, which use .text to make a "ellipsis" effect using jQuery.

There must be some bugs in my code, you should fix them yourself. I just point out a way.

```js
$(".tdsp+td div div").each(function() {
  var $dom = $(this);
  $dom.css({
    'white-space': "normal"
  });
  var text = $dom.text();
  var lineEndIndex;
  $dom.text("a");
  setTimeout(function() {
    var lineHeight = $dom.height();
    var textIndex = 1;

    function addText() {
      $dom.text(text.slice(0, textIndex));
      if ($dom.height() > lineHeight) {
        $dom.text(text.slice(0, textIndex - 4) + "...");
        lineEndIndex = textIndex;
        return;
      }
      textIndex++;
      setTimeout(addText);
    }
    addText();
  });
  $dom.on("mouseenter", function() {
    var textIndex = lineEndIndex;

    function addText() {
      $dom.text(text.slice(0, textIndex));
      if (textIndex === text.length) {
        return;
      }
      textIndex++;
      setTimeout(addText);
    }
    addText();
  });
  $dom.on("mouseleave", function() {
    var textIndex = text.length;

    function addText() {
      $dom.text(text.slice(0, textIndex));
      if (textIndex === lineEndIndex - 4) {
        $dom.text(text.slice(0, textIndex) + "...");
        return;
      }
      textIndex--;
      setTimeout(addText);
    }
    addText();
  });

});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
  background: #FFF;
  height: 55px;
  max-width: 200px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tdsp {
  overflow: hidden;
}

table td>div {
  position: relative;
}

table td>div div {
  background: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: -11px;
}

table td>div div:hover {
  white-space: normal;
  z-index: 1;
}

th {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="bordered centered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Test</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Test</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Test</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Test</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Test</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Test</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Test</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsp">Test</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
But I'm confused by something ... With connected Materialize this doesn't work. Hmm.

Comment: BTW, your nickname is somehow difficult to @

Comment: @Марк What does "connected Materialize" mean?

Comment: Materialize framework: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css

Comment: If you move my code to your project, you must add jquery lib and modify the selector ".tdsp+td div div". Generally if this demo works in your browser, you'd better understand it and port it to your page by yourself. @Марк

Comment: @Марк and it's 0:44 in china, time to sleep

Comment: Thank you. I will look for a problem. Good night!

Comment: Hey guy, if you are satisfied with this answer you can accept it.@Марк